# Using scanner to assign value to a variable in another class?

Tags: java

I'm trying to assign a value to a variable in another class using input from the user. 
My goal is to use the "fullName" setter value that was called in the
secondary class but I keep getting the error "cannot resolve symbol fullName". 
I think it may be because the variable in the other class is private, but I edited the visibility to public and that didn't change anything. 
How can I do this?

Here's my code:

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter your full name:\n");
     fullName = scan.nextLine();
    }
}

// Secondary class
public class Person {

    private int id;
    private String fullName;

    // Constructor
    public Person(String fullName, String id){

    }

    // Setters
    public static void setName(String fullName){
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public static void setid(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    //getters
    public String getfullName(){
        return fullName;
    }

    public int getid(){
        return id;
    }
```

Comment: The setters must not ne static.

Comment: it is always helpful to provide the error message. Otherwise, "I keep getting an error" is not informative enough for us to help

Comment: The error I'm getting is "cannot resolve symbol 'fullName' "

Comment: new Person().setName(scan.nextLine()); use this

Comment: @MCEmperor I tried removing the static before but it still gives me the error above along with an additional message for the this statement for the setter saying "Static member Person.fullName accessed via instance reference"

Comment: @Onkar Musale That I would not do, since it creates an Object that isn't assigned to a variable and therefore can't be accessed afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access a `Person` members you have to declare a `Person` object in the `Main` class first.
After you do, you will have an instance of `Person` and then you could use his members / methods.

Another 2 tips:

1. The setters shouldn't be static.
2. Your constructor does nothing. Modify it that the `fullName` and `id` variables will be assigned to the matching member:

> ```
> public Person(String fullName, int id) {
>     this.fullName = fullName;
>     this.id = id;
> }
> ```

If you don't want this behaviour, you can write an empty constructor, which doesn't receive any inputs.

Comment: Can you give some advice on how to modify the constructor so that variables will be assigned to matching members? I'm not sure how to go about doing that

Comment: I have added the code to my comment. If you liked my answer, please click on the 'up' arrow for me :)

Comment: Leibobitz In the case where my constructor is modified so that variables will be assigned to the matching members, do I no longer have to write this code in main?     

- `obj.setFullName(fullName);
  obj.setId(id);
`
Or can it just be done like this:     

`Person obj = new Person(fullName, id);`

Comment: Yes, exactly. You are assigning the values to each member inside the constructor. This is the correct way to do so. Please upvote my answers :)

Comment: I ran into a issue while changing it, my setters are no longer being called and it's just going straight into creating the object. Should this be an issue? Thank you, I upvoted!

Comment: First, I cant see the upvote on the first comment. Second  yes, in this way your setters will not be used but that's not a problem. The setters are there for your benefit, and it is possible to use them somewhere in the future. For example, let's say that in your program you have created some person and use it. After some time, that person want to change his name,. In this case you dont need to create new person with different name, you can just use the setter to the existing one.

Comment: Thank you. Also, the upvote won't appear since my reputation is less than 15, I am new here.

Comment: Np. If you need anything else just comment

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is because in class Main, you did not declare fullName. 
Read about variable scoping to understand more about this (intuitively, the fullName you define in the class Person is not visible from the other class Main, because it's declared as private, as it should be).

The solution is quite simple:

1. define `fullName` as String in Main class,
2. create an instance of Person, say `person`, and
3. call `person.setName(fullName);` method (which must not be static) with the value of fullName that you read.

Here is the code for this solution:

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter your full name:\n");
     String fullName = scan.nextLine();
     Person person = new Person();
     person.setName(fullName);
    }
}

// Secondary class
public class Person {

    private int id;
    private String fullName;

    // Constructor
    public Person(String fullName, String id){
         this.id = id;
         this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public Person(){             
    }

    // Setters
    public void setName(String fullName){
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public void setid(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    //getters
    public String getfullName(){
        return fullName;
    }

    public int getid(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

Another option is to add a new constructor that takes only one argument (String fullName), and directly create a Person instance as `Person person = new Person(fullName);`.

Answer (score 0):

1) You shall create an object of type Person.
2) Define a string to hold the name.
3) Call the function.

```
 String pName =  scan.nextLine();
 Person myPerson = new Person();
 myPerson.setFullName(pName);
```

-

```
public class Person {

private int id;
private String fullName;

public void setName(String fullName){
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

public void setid(int id){
    this.id = id;
} 
public String getfullName(){
    return fullName;
}
}
```

Also your setters shouldn't be static.

Comment: This cannot be compiled since his constructor receive 2 inputs.

Comment: You are right, he can use the default constructor. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

> I have made following changes:

1. Created **object of Person class** in your main class and created **input for id** too along with **declared fullName as string** variable.
2. Used **set method** to set the value to Person class. In this case id and fullName **setters** are used to set those values to person class.
3. Replaced **nextLine()** method by simply **next()** method.
4. **toString()** method is added in Person class to print Person Object values.

> Refer below mentioned code:

```
// Main Class
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your id:");
        int id = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter your full name:");
        String fullName = scan.next();

        Person obj = new Person();
        obj.setFullName(fullName);
        obj.setId(id);

        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

```
// Secondary class
public class Person {

    private int id;
    private String fullName;

    public Person() {
        super();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", fullName=" + fullName + "]";
    }
```

Comment: This cannot be compiled since his constructor receive 2 inputs.